# Setting up Flask with FlaskClassy

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

My folder root app.py  looks like this

```
import application
if __name__ == '__main__':
application.app.run()
```

I have a folder called application with `__init__.py` and three folders: controllers, models and views.

The `__init__.py` Looks like this

```
__version__ = '0.1'
from application.controllers import QuotesView
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('application')
QuotesView.register(app)
```

My `controllers` folder has two files `__init__.py` and `QuotesView.py` as shown below:
`QuotesView.py`

```
from flask.ext.classy import FlaskView, route
# we'll make a list to hold some quotes for our app
quotes = [
"A noble spirit embiggens the smallest man! ~ Jebediah Springfield",
"If there is a way to do it better... find it. ~ Thomas Edison",
"No one knows what he can do till he tries. ~ Publilius Syrus"
]

class QuotesView(FlaskView):
    @route('/')
    def index(self):
        return "<br>".join(quotes)
    def before_request(self, name):
        print("something is happening to a widget")

    def after_request(self, name, response):
        print("something happened to a widget")
        return response
```

And `__init__.py` looks like this:

```
import os
import glob
__all__ = [os.path.basename(
f)[:-3] for f in glob.glob(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/*.py")]
```

When I run `python app.py` I get an attribute missing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
import application
File "/home/ace/flask/application/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
QuotesView.register(app)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'register'
```

I cant seem to figure out where the error is though i feel its my importing. I am pretty new to python, so it might be something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not importing the `QuotesView` class. You're import the the `QuotesView` module. So in order for this to work correctly, you can do one of two things:

1.Import the class from the module:

```
from application.controllers.QuotesView import QuotesView
```

2.Access the class from the import module

```
from application.controllers import QuotesView
QuotesView.QuotesView.register(app)
```

Method 1 is a lot cleaner in my opinion.